# separate between owner of the page and viewer

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I have a profile page that allow users to send friend request to other users and I have a friend request table with fields : id mem1 mem2 datetime

mem1 : is the viewer user for the profile page 
mem2 : is the owner of the profile page

when the mem1 send the request the system check if the the user is the owner so it not allow him to send request to it self .

if not the user send request and the table will fill  the required data

but the error i get is that the system always  display that the user is the owner and the viewer which is wrong.

this is all the code  but the problem is in the checking  if the user is the owner or a viewer ...

## profile.php

```
if($username!=$login_user)
{
    $interactionBox='<div class = "InteractionLinksDiv">
    <a href= "#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers(\'add_friend\');">Add as Friend</a>
    </div>';
    $isOwner = "no";
}
//check if the logued in user is equal from the url username
else
{
    $interactionBox='<div style="display:inline; border:#CCC 1px solid; padding:5px; background-color:#E4E4E4; color:#999; font-size:11px;">
    Other members will see  links to interact with you here.
    </div>';
    $isOwner = "yes";
}
?>

function addAsFriend(a,b){
   //alert("Member with id:" + a + "request friendship with the memeber with id:" + b);
  var url = "script_for_profile/request_as_friend.php";
  $("#add_friend").text("please wait...").show();
  $.post(url,{request:"requestFreindship",mem1:a,mem2:b},function(data){
    $("#add_friend").html(data).show().fadeOut(12000);
  });
}

<div class="interactContainers" id="add_friend">
               <div align="right"><a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers('add_friend');">Cancel</a></div>
               Add <?php echo $username ?> as Friend?&nbsp;

               <a href ="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:addAsFriend(<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>,<?php echo $userid; ?>);">Yes</a>
               </div>
```

## request_as_friend.php

```
<?php
require_once('../include/connect.php'); 
   if(@!$login){
         session_start();
        }
        $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
         $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
         $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
         $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
         $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
ob_start();
$username = "";
   if(isset($_GET['u']))
   {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
        if(ctype_alnum($username)){
                //check  user exists
       $check = mysql_query("SELECT user_name, first_name FROM user WHERE user_name = '$username'");
       if(mysql_num_rows($check)==1)
       {
           $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
           $username = $get['user_name'];
           $fname = $get['first_name'];
           var_dump($username);
           var_dump($fname);
       }
       else
       {
           echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://localhost/lam-el-chamel/index.php\">";
           exit();
       }
     }
   }



$mem1 = $login_user;
$mem2 = $username;

//var we need for  both  members
$mem1=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_POST['mem1']);
$mem2=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_POST['mem2']);

if(!$mem1||!$mem2)
{
    echo "Error .missing data";
    exit();
}

if($mem1==$mem2)
{
    echo "Error you can not add yourself as friend";
    exit();
}



 if($_POST['request']=="requestFreindship")
 {
     //check that  there  is not  a request  pending  where this viewer  is requesting  this profile  owner
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id  FROM friend_requests WHERE mem1='$mem1' AND mem2='$mem2'LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
     $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
     if($numRows > 0)
     {
         echo "You have a friend request pending already  for this member. they must approve  it when they view their request list";
         exit();
     }
      //check that  there  is not  a request  pending  where this profile owner  is not already requesting  this viewer
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id  FROM friend_requests WHERE mem1='$mem2' AND mem2='$mem1'LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
     $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
     if($numRows > 0)
     {
         echo "This user has requested you as friend already! Check  your friend  Request on your profile";
         exit();
     }
     $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO friend_requests(mem1,mem2,timedate) VALUES('$mem1','$mem2',now())") or die (mysql_error("friend request  insertionn error"));
     //$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pms(to,from,time,sub,msg) VALUES('$mem2','XXXXX',now(),'New Friend Request','YOU Have a New  friend request waiting for approval.<br /><br />Navigate to your profile and check  your friend request.<br /><br />Thank you.')") or die (mysql_error("friend request PM insertionn error"));

  echo "Friend Request sent successfully. this member must approve the request";
  exit();    
 }
?>
```

Comment: Where are you declaring the `$username` and the `$login_user` in the `profile.php` script?

Comment: @ MISJHA $login user is  a session variable and the $username  is declaring in the profile at the first lines